# Нет перевода подсказок для вкладок на странице активности пользователя

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/current

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В традусёре тоже нет. Кажется, захардкодили.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ [угу](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345101/260198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Просил на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345101/260198) добавить эти слова в transifex.

Вчера эти слова были добавлены. Все переводы обновил. Появятся с релизом новой версии движка.

Comment: А теперь ещё раз - те же фразы, но с `this user` вместо `you`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPjuS.png

Comment: @Qwertiy ух. Напомни на выходных, добавлю)